# How to group SQL data in separate arrays with PHP foreach loop?

Tags: php

I have four tables: users, teachers, quizes and battle_users.

user table:

[image: user table]

in users table the value 1 of teacher means the user is a teacher and value 0 means he is a student.

teacher table:

[image: teacher table]

In the teachers table, I have the ids of teachers and students who invited and added each other. I am trying to group the students of each teacher in an array so that later the first and second and third students would get rewards and the rest of the students would get another reward.
I am trying to get an array like this.

> [i43 => [ id => 53, id => 9], 148 => [ id => 2, id => 12 , id => 15, id => 1, id => 11]]

How to do that because my query gives me the entire list of students in one array?

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/common.php';
$common = new Common();

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    http_response_code(500);
    die(json_encode(['message' => "Database connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error]));
}

$teachers = [];
$students = [];
$marks = [];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where teacher=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($teachers, $row);
    }
}

foreach ($teachers as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "SELECT `user_id` FROM teacher WHERE friend_id = '" . $value['id'] . "' UNION ALL SELECT  `friend_id` FROM teacher WHERE user_id = '" . $value['id'] . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($students, $row);
        }
    }
}

foreach ($students as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "select name,userId, email, sum(mark) as mark from
                    (select u.name,u.email,q.userId,sum(q.`correct`+q.`bonus`)as mark from quizes q join users u on q.userId= '" . $value['user_id'] . "' AND u.id='" . $value['user_id'] . "' " . $wheres . " group by q.userId
                    UNION ALL
                    select u.name,u.email,q.user_Id as userId ,sum(q.`score`+q.`rewards`)as mark from battle_users q join users u on q.user_id= '" . $value['user_id'] . "' AND u.id='" . $value['user_id'] . "' " . $where . " group by q.user_id) t group by userId order by mark ASC limit 50";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($marks, $row);
        }
    }
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: you'd get more help putting your DB schema instead of the print_r dump that you have right up there. and yes, avoid n+1 as much as possible. you're better off using joins instead

Comment: Thank you I tried to upload images of the tables. I am new to sql and php so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why did you delete the old question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665409/how-to-group-sql-data-in-seperate-arrays-with-php-foreach-loop I was waiting for you to update the question with more details.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: I updated it but it didn't get approved so I deleted it and asked another question. Thank you for the advice and actually this code was written by another dev working on the same app. I was hired just to do some tasks so I used his code and modified it according to my tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should re-do the structure of your tables;

table_user:
user_ID | user_NAME | user_TYPE | user_PARENT ...
1 | Yasar | 2 | 0
2 | Abdul | 1 | 1
3 | Aisha | 1 | 1
...

table_types
type_ID | type_NAME ...
1 | teacher
2 | student
...

So you can e.g. `"SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE user_TYPE = '1'"` for all teachers or if you have the user_ID of a teacher and want the students, `"SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE user_TYPE = '2' AND user_PARENT = '--teacherID--'"`

Or looping through the table like

```
// building type-array
$typesByID = array();
$typesByNAME = array();
$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM user_types');
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $typesByID[$row['type_ID']] = $row['type_NAME'];
        $typesByNAME[$row['type_NAME']] = $row['type_ID'];
    }
}

// build teacher-array
$teachers = array();
$query = 'SELECT * FROM user_table;';
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (isset($typesByID[$row['user_TYPE']]) && $typesByID[$row['user_TYPE']] == 'teacher') {
            $teachers[$row['user_ID']]['userdata'] = $row;
        }
        elseif (isset($typesByID[$row['user_TYPE']]) && $typesByID[$row['user_TYPE']] == 'student') {
            $teachers[$row['user_PARENT']]['students'][] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I have no control over the tables so I cannot change them.